# Data sent as ArrayBuffer is being recieved as Blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) module for a WebSocket server in nodejs. On the server side, I have a `Uint8Array` that I send to the client using code very much like this,

```
var data = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
clientSock.send(data, {
    binary: true
});
```

However, on the client side (both the latest Chrome and Firefox), the data is recieved as a `Blob` object. I know I can process this back into a `Uint8Array` using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). But I want to receive it as an `ArrayBuffer` in the first place. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as I finished writing this question, I happened to find the answer on my own. According to the [MDN documentation for `WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Attributes), there is a `binaryType` property that has to be set to either `"blob"` or `"arraybuffer"`, and it determines the format in which the data is received. By changing the client-side code like so,

```
var sock = new WebSocket("<the server address>");
sock.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

Now all the binary data from the server is received as ArrayBuffers, as expected.